# Bash "read" builtin results differ from declared in manuals

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Have the script rec.sh(on Gentoo, x86_64):

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do

    if read -t 0 ; then echo up read succ ;
     else echo up read fail ;
    fi

    filename=test.mp3
    cat >>$filename

    if read -t 0 ; then echo bottom read succ ;
     else echo bottom read fail ;
    fi

    read -t 0 && break
done
```

Bash manual from GNU about the read builtin:

> If timeout is 0, read returns immediately, without trying to read any data. The exit status is 0 if input is available on the specified file descriptor, or the read will return EOF, non-zero otherwise.

Bash 'help read':

```
If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns
                immediately, without trying to read any data, returning
                success only if input is available on the specified
                file descriptor.
```

```
Exit Status:
    The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out
    (in which case it's greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs,
    or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
```

For test I use writing audio stream to stdin of my script just to have a low sane bitrate stream. This is not a clue of the question. I added comments marked with () inside code snippet for reader's convenient.

```
# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
10197 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
31972 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
# arecord -D dsnoop:0,0,0,s16_le,16000 -t wav -c 2 -f s16_le -r 16000 2>>/dev/null | lame -q 9 -m j --cbr -b 40 - - 2>>/dev/null | ./rec.sh &
[1] 10200
up read fail **(Why? Pipe is valid, I expect to have "success" here corresponding to docs)**
# ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
10198 pts/3    00:00:00 arecord
10199 pts/3    00:00:00 lame
10200 pts/3    00:00:00 rec.sh
10203 pts/3    00:00:00 cat
10204 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
31972 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
# kill 10203 **(killing cat to test if it will respawn)**
Terminated
bottom read fail **(Why? Pipe is valid(?), I expect to have "success" here corresponding to docs)**
up read fail **(Why? Pipe is valid(?), I expect to have "success" here corresponding to docs)**
# kill 10198 **(killing input source to test script sanely closes on some errors)**
bottom read succ **(Why? Writer's end of pipe is closed(!) Why I have to expect "success" from read builtin here to have my script gracefully exiting the loop?)**
[1]+  Done
```

BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="5" [1]="0" [2]="18" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='5.0.18(1)-release'

Some logic of filename generation was omitted for simplicity.
Actually I work on audio recording scripts and this piece is used to constanly record mp3 stream to file reopening new file every time cron HUPs it(usually at every hour).

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Remove #!/bin/sh, put #!/bin/bash, test again, edit question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> up read fail **(Why?

It runs *concurrently*, *asynchronously*. That means, `read -t 0` *may* execute *before* `lame` is able to write any data. And it will.

> bottom read fail **(Why? Pipe is valid(?)

Same as above.

> up read fail **(Why? Pipe is valid(?)

As above. It does not wait for data, it doesn't check if pipe is closed. It checks if there are any immediately available data. If `lame` was not able to write anything, there aren't. And `lame` does a lot of buffering.

> bottom read succ **(Why? Writer's end of pipe

Pipe is closed, and `read -t 0` calls `select()` system call. Now `select()` checks if `read()` system call *will* return immediately. `read()` will return immediately, with `EOF`! So `select()` returns 1, so `read -t 0` succeeds - you can call `read` and it will immediately read `EOF` from the stream and fail.

Comment: Thank you for strong answer! May I ask what would you recommend to test validity of pipe in my case?

Comment: Nothing? After `cat` returns, you know that the pipe is closed. Just `cat`, then exit. I do not see a logic in your script to use non-blocking read. Remove your script and `lame .... outputfile`

Comment: Oh. You are right in context of the my question. The logic is to kill cat sometimes intentionally to change filename for cat to output to. And this is in turn needed cause source to this script comes from tee... Generally speaking: arecord reads raw audio, lame encodes to mp3 stream, tee distribute to icecast client and to my rec.sh for storing in the form of mp3 files with one file every hour.

Comment: ... all this is about to have only one encoding process for cpu resource economy.

Comment: `The logic is to kill cat` By doing that, you will lose data to stdin buffering inside `cat`. That is super flawed. You might want to ask a separate question explaining when exactly you want to "kill cat sometimes". You want to use `python` or `split` or other program that does exactly that. In Bash, you would `while your_sometimes_condition && read -n 1024; chunk; do printf "%s" "$chunk" >> outfile; done`, but definitely _not_ call a separate external program that you plan to kill if you care about your data.

Comment: `of mp3 files with one file every hour` Great - remove `lame` and use  `ffmpeg` with `-segment_time`. I do not think the output of `lame` can be split into parts - I think an mp3 comes with a header, you can't chunk in the middle.

Comment: Very good ideas. I'll think in that way. Thank you for time spent on my questions.